# how can i calculate mutual friends/followers efficiently?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, typeorm, system-design

i need to calculate mutual friends between users, right now it is working fine, but i don't think it will work for users who have a large follower base, it will take a long to load and compare. please suggest me good db design/query(if needed).
I've created tables and have a query like this:

table:

```
export enum FollowStatus {
  REQUESTED = "REQUESTED",
  APPROVED = "APPROVED",
  DECLINED = "DECLINED"
}

@Entity("followers")
export class Followers {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  @Property()
  id: number;

  @Property()
  @Column()
  followerId: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Users, { eager: true })
  @JoinColumn({ name: "followerId" })
  follower: Users;

  @Property()
  @Column()
  followedId: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Users, { eager: true })
  @JoinColumn({ name: "followedId" })
  followed: Users;

  @Column({
    type: "enum",
    enum: FollowStatus,
    default: FollowStatus.REQUESTED
  })
  @Property()
  status: FollowStatus;
}
```

query:

```
  async getFollowers(userId: string, page: number, limit: number) {
    const builder: SelectQueryBuilder<Followers> = this.createQueryBuilder("followers")
      .where("followers.followedId = :userId", { userId })
      .andWhere("followers.status = :status", { status: "APPROVED" })
      .leftJoinAndSelect("followers.follower", "follower")
      .leftJoinAndSelect("follower.followers", "followerFollowers")
      .take(limit)
      .skip((page - 1) * limit);

    const followers = await builder.getManyAndCount();
    return followers;
  }
```

main function:

```
async getFollowers(userId: string, page: number, limit: number) {
    page = page || DEFAULT_PAGE_NUMBER;
    limit = limit || DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE;

    const followers = await this.followersRepository.getFollowers(userId, page, limit);
    const myFollowers = followers[0].map((follower) => follower.followerId);

    const response: SearchResponse<FollowerUsersInterface> = {
      data: await Promise.all(
        followers[0].map(async (user) => {
          const isFollowing = user.follower.followers.findIndex((follower) => follower.followerId == userId);

          const userFollowers = user.follower.followers;

          // count mutual followers, exluding the user itself
          const mutualFollowersCount = userFollowers.filter((follower) => {
            if (follower.followerId !== user.followerId) {
              return myFollowers.some((myFollower) => myFollower === follower.followerId && follower.status === FollowStatus.APPROVED);
            }
          }).length;

          return {
            isFollowing: isFollowing > -1,
            userId: user.follower.id,
            userName: user.follower.userName,
            profilePic: await this.s3.getSignedUrl(user.follower.profilePic),
            mutualFollowers: mutualFollowersCount
          } as FollowerUsersInterface;
        })
      ),
      totalCount: followers[1]
    };

    return response;
  }
```

sample db records:

```
# id    status     followerId     followedId
20    APPROVED    3              PBpq
22    APPROVED    1              PBpq
24    APPROVED    2              PBpq
25    APPROVED    PBpq           2
26    APPROVED    1              2
28    APPROVED    INOr           PBpq
29    APPROVED    2NAo           PBpq
34    APPROVED    1              2NAo
```

- expected output:
- assume your userId is PBpq
- if I visit userId 2,  i would see my mutual follower count as **1**
- explaination: **me** and **userId 1** both are following **userId 2** so, i will get **mutual count 1**

Comment: Maybe a sample database table with sample data and desired output will make things more clear

Comment: sure i'll add sample db recoreds

Comment: So you need mutual friends with one user at a time? And what is PBpq, 2NAo in `followerId` and `followedId`. are they not foreign keys?

Comment: Some users have numeric ids and some have strings?

Comment: Should the query be limited to "approved" connections?

Comment: "need to calculate" -- Are you are looking for "how many" or "who" (ie, a list of users)?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table(s) involved, and the current SQL being generated.  Indexes for the tables, reformulating the querys, and/or rearranging the tables are likely to be involved in the answer to your question.

Comment: @Asgar PBpq and 2NAO are user ids and yes followerId and followedId are foreign keys, I'm fetching current users **followers**  (with the list of their follower too) and then in **main function** I'm calculating mutual followers.

Comment: @RickJames users have ids in string, and I need to count mutual follower who actually are approved,

Comment: Where's the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed approach, now im getting user's followers list

```
  async getFollowers(userId: string, page: number, limit: number) {
    const builder: SelectQueryBuilder<Followers> = this.createQueryBuilder("followers")
      .where("followers.followedId = :userId", { userId })
      .andWhere("followers.status = :status", { status: "APPROVED" })
      .leftJoinAndSelect("followers.follower", "follower")
      .take(limit)
      .skip((page - 1) * limit);

    const followers = await builder.getManyAndCount();
    return followers;
  },
```

then iterate thru it one bye one and get mutual follower list:

```
 async getMutualFollowersCount(myuserId: string, userId: string): Promise<number> {
    const subQuery: SelectQueryBuilder<Followers> = this.createQueryBuilder("subFollowers")
      .where("subFollowers.followedId = :myuserId", { myuserId })
      .andWhere("subFollowers.status = :status", { status: "APPROVED" })
      .select("subFollowers.followerId");

    const builder: SelectQueryBuilder<Followers> = this.createQueryBuilder("followers")
      .where("followers.followerId = :userId", { userId })
      .andWhere("followers.status = :status", { status: "APPROVED" })
      .andWhere(`followers.followedId IN (${subQuery.getQuery()})`)
      .setParameters(subQuery.getParameters());

    const mutualFollowersCount = await builder.getCount();
    return mutualFollowersCount;
  },
```